# How to display datepicker selected value on label

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker2Change(Sender: TObject);
var
day:tdatetime;
begin
Datetimepicker2.date:=day;
label1.caption:=(FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy', day));
```

Hi!

I wanted to display selected date from datepicker on label but the label just show me the '30.12.1899' date of day and not the date which i selected from the datepicker.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings and then heed them. The compiler will tell you that you are using an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 6):

Your assignment should be reversed

```
day := Datetimepicker2.date;
```

You can also write that code without using local variable

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.caption:=(FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy', Datetimepicker2.date));
end;
```